# Calculating the size of an array by dereferencing its pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

A colleague of mine asked this question: [Array size in multidimensional array with pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850475/array-size-in-multidimensional-array-with-pointers)

The answers are all pretty definitive in that you cannot work out the size of an array that is referenced by a pointer.

My initial thought was to first dereference the pointer and then calculate the size of the array itself. Why would this not work? Does dereferencing the pointer not give you the full array?

Comment: nope, just the first element in the array - which in of itself is meaningless in this context...Size is not a piece of information that is *embedded* in the underlying representation...

Comment: It's like unwind said. If you want to retain size information, store it. Or use a convention (such as the last element is always nullified).

Comment: You may find this useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/5655614/1458030

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There *is* no "full array" in C, at least not as you seem to expect there to be.

An array can always be represented as a pointer to the first element, together with information about the array's layout.

This information is not available at runtime, it's part of the type for actual arrays (like `int foo[6][2][12]`) so the compiler can just use that knowledge directly when generating code to access elements. As pointed out by Lundin, the exception is variable-length arrays (introduced in C99). For those, the compiler must add run-time code to make `sizeof` work.

If you pass `foo` to a function taking `int *`, there's no way to magically re-create the dimensionality data from that. All pointers to `int` look the same, you can pass `&foo[0][0][0]` or just the address of a plain `int`.

Comment: A parenthesis: except the special case of VLAs, where sizeof is evaluated in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way in C to determine the size of an array. Arrays are just pointers to a memory location. You have to know how much memory in that location is part of an array.

That's why most methods from the standard library which use arrays either need nul-terminated arrays, or an additional argument telling them their length.

Comment: Arrays are not just pointers to memory locations. They *decay* to such pointers when passed around.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays. When you spread misinformation like this we get questions like the current one...